# android web scraping dynamic content jsoup

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

i am developing an android app which should track shipments from israel post website. since they don't have any api, I am trying to manipulate the website with setting specific links and parsing the html with jsoup but it is not working because the tracking info is loaded dynamically. i tried combining jsoup with selenium but i am not sure it can be implemented in android environment since i am getting build errors does anyone have any technique or  approach for this task? i would very appreciate it.[image: trying to capture the info in blue box]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get your data from this url:
http://www.israelpost.co.il/itemtrace.nsf/trackandtraceNOHEJSON?openagent&lang=EN&itemcode=RR123445677IL

Check this Java code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IsraeliPost {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String URL = "http://www.israelpost.co.il/itemtrace.nsf/trackandtraceNOHEJSON?openagent&lang=EN&itemcode=";
        String itemNumber = "RR123445677IL";

        try {
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL + itemNumber)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            String jsonResponse = response.body();
            ItemData itemData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, ItemData.class);
            String itemCodeInfo = itemData.getItemcodeinfo();

            Document document = Jsoup.parse(itemCodeInfo);

            Elements table = document.select("table").select("tbody");

            for (Element raw : table) {
                Elements tds = raw.select("td");
                for (Element td : tds) {
                    System.out.println(td.text());

                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class ItemData {

        @SerializedName("itemcodeinfo")
        private String mItemcodeinfo;

        public String getItemcodeinfo() {
            return mItemcodeinfo;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Date Postal Unit City Description 30/01/2015 Shikun Memshalti Nahariya
>   Delivered to an empowered designate of the addressee 28/01/2015 Shikun
>   Memshalti Nahariya Arrived at the postal unit for delivery to
>   addressee 27/01/2015 Jaffo Tel Aviv Yaffo Received for mailing and was
>   forwarded for processing

Comment: Works like a charm You just saved my day Thanks!